# Jupyter notebook in pycharm does not display inline plots

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pycharm, jupyter

Jupyter notebook in my PyCharm on Windows can display simple matplotlib plots but cannot display image through e.g. imshow. What is the best way to address this? I have reproduced this on two separate windows 10 and windows 8 laptops.

Example here:

[image]

Comment: For those who have this problem please comment in this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22165

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to use skimage in my jupyter notebook on Windows. I solved with a workaround to show my image using cv2.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(C:/Users/src/photos/img.jpg)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Hope this is helpful. I am pretty new to all this.